# How important is it to fix race conditions for small primitives?

Tags: ios, thread-safety, atomic

I'm working on an iOS app and I've found some race conditions in my app for nonatomic `BOOL` and `NSInteger` properties. I was curious, does it really matter if these get fixed? Like, if I have a read and a write at the same time for a `BOOL` and I don't care whether it uses the old or new value of the `BOOL`, as long as it uses one of them, isn't that OK? I'd be surprised if a read could come up with 1 when the start and end values of the `BOOL` from the write are 0.

Comment: It's quite unlikely the question has a sensible general answer outside of the specifics of a particular implementation.

Comment: I've clarified that it's an iOS-specific question

Comment: That doesn't really clarify anything. You're basically asking 'is some race condition important in some situation that nobody can examine but you'. Who knows?

Comment: Another way of putting this question, since you don't seem to have read it very carefully, is, if the start and end values are the same, is a concurrent read guaranteed to get that value?

Comment: My feeling is that if you've identified an issue you should resolve it before it bites you. Wwdc  Video 404 debugging with Xcode 9 from 2017 has about 10 minutes near the end of it devoted to how Xcode 9 identifies race conditions for you. They obviously take them seriously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a “benign” race, discussed in WWDC 2016 video [Thread Sanitizer and Static Analysis](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/412/?time=753) (at about 14:40).

They point out that no race should be considered benign because:

- It’s contingent upon the particular hardware architecture you are using, and you have no assurances that such a data race will continue to be benign under different architectures;
- All data races (benign or otherwise) are considered to be an undefined behavior from C/C++ standards.
- While this may not be an issue in your code, compilers are free to reorder instructions oblivious to what other threads might be doing, so in some cases, in the absence of some synchronization mechanism, it can lead to “very subtle bugs.”

Bottom line, even though it’s likely not essential to fix these benign races, Apple advises that you do so, regardless. Fortunately, since you’re dealing with Objective-C, it’s easily remedied by making the properties `atomic`.

Comment: I agree with Rob. My feeling is that if you've identified an issue you should resolve it before it bites you. Wwdc  Video 404 debugging with Xcode 9 from 2017 has about 10 minutes near the end of it devoted to how Xcode 9 identifies race conditions for you. They obviously take them seriously.