# Can I settle a race condition with BOOLs

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I have a network operation that invokes a block when it's done:

```
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // call this method's completion handler
```

For my app to begin, I'd like to run this along with some `UIView` block animations to start an app.  Before the app can proceed, both the user animations must be seen and the network operation must complete.  I'd prefer to have these async things happen at the same time, and I've tried something like this:

```
__block BOOL animationsDone=NO, networkDone=NO;

[self doUIViewBlockAnimations:^(BOOL finished) {
    animationsDone = YES;
    if (networkDone) [self startTheApp];
}];

[self doNetworkThing:^(id result) {
    networkDone = YES;
    if (animationsDone) [self startTheApp];
}];
```

This seems to run fine, and I think it is safe because these blocks must both run on the main queue, so I think they cannot run simultaneously.  But I'm a little shaky on this stuff (e.g. like what `nonatomic` does, even though I put it on every property).

Is there any risk that both of these blocks complete but somehow the state of the BOOLs gets mixed up and the app doesn't start?  That could be a hard bug to figure out later on.

Comment: I believe race condition for primitive type has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449492/how-important-is-it-to-fix-race-conditions-for-small-primitives